# I have a multidim array with sub arrays and i have to print only id on main index in php josn.How can I do by using a loop?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Simple Array Example. Here i just have to print series ID

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [series_id] => 42
                [userid] => 1
                [views] => 0
                [seasons] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [season_id] => 58
                                [series_id] => 42
                                [episodes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                            [videoid] => 1223
                                            )
                           )
              )
)
```

How to write php code so i can print the required data? Foreach loop will be suitable or for loop?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to get all series_ids of the top level of the array.

With a for loop:

```
$series_ids = [];
for ($i = 0, $iMax = count($arr); $i < $iMax; $i++) {
  $series_ids[] = $arr[$i]["series_id"];
}
```

A shorter version is with array_column():

```
$series_ids = array_column($arr, "series_id");
```

Both will give you with *print_r($series_ids)*:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 42
)
```

Comment: thanku so much .exactly this is what i needed

Comment: its not displaying with echo if I want to display in table

Comment: **echo** only works with scalar values like strings, numbers, etc. For arrays you need to use print_r($series_ids) or var_dump($series_ids). If you need only one element the same applies, use echo for scalar elements of an array, and print_r or var_dump for elements of an array which are arrays themselves. So in your case to echo 42 you do: echo $series_ids[0]; // prints 42